# Ruby on rails drop down box Beginner lvl

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am a beginner in ROR, like I know it for a month (school assignment and we don't get a cursus we need to use 'google')

So I want a dropdown box with a list of all my cities. Then if I pick a city I need to save the city_id in my database together with the date. The code I have so far seem to work except when I click on save it says that city is empty (and it can't be empty because of the failsave)

this is my code

```
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :stad_id %><br />
    <% cities_array = Stad.all.map { |stad| [stad.naam, stad.land] } %>
    <%= select_tag(Stad, options_for_select(cities_array))  %>


    </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :datum %><br />
    <% datum = Time.now.to_s(:db) %>
    <%= f.text_field :datum, :value => datum.inspect, :readonly => true %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I don't really know what I am doing wrong except I have an eery feeling I don't actually give the command to save it.

help is much thanked
sincerely
Robin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things I notice here that are wrong.

1) Put the creation of the cities_array into your controller, not in your view:

```
def edit
  @something = Something.find(params[:id])
  @cities_array = ... whatever ...
end
```

2) When creating your cities_array, you need to specify the ID of the city as the second parameter, like this:

```
@cities_array = Stad.all.map { |stad| [stad.naam, stad.id] }
```

3) The select_tag call isn't for Stad, it's for the model you're trying to save. For example, your form might look like this:

```
<%= form_for @something %>
  <%= f.label :city %>
  <%= f.select :city_id, @cities_array %>
  # or!
  <%= select :something, :city_id, @cities_array %>
<% end %>
```

I hoep this clears things up for you.

Comment: It kinda does but when I put the array in the controllere like this.         'code'@cities_array = Stad.all.map { |stad| [stad.naam, stad.id] }'code' and my form looks now like this. 'code'<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :stad_id %><br />
    
    <%= select :stad_naam, :stad_id, @cities_array %>
  </div>'code'  It now says undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass